Page jumps after hiding content
How can the jumping be prevented?
Here is a video of the issue: https://streamable.com/t2cyu3
I have a grid with many grid items.
This grid can be expanded or collapsed to show or hide its content.
The expand/collapse is being done by adding and removing a class named "collapsed" in javascript.
The expand/collapse happens when you press the "toggle" button.
If you scroll below the last grid item (the blue boxes), press the toggle button the page will jump to the bottom of the page.
How can you prevent the page from scrolling down?


const toggleButton = document.getElementById("toggle-button")

const grid = document.getElementById("grid")

let isCollapsed = false

toggleButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  isCollapsed = !isCollapsed

  if (isCollapsed) {
    grid.classList.add("collapsed")
  } else {
    grid.classList.remove("collapsed")
  }
})
body {
  padding: 72px;
}

.filler-content {
  background: seashell;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1600px;
}

#grid {
  background: black;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  gap: 16px;
}

.grid-item {
  background: blue;
  padding: 80px;
}

#toggle-button {
  background: orange;
  padding: 16px;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 4px;
}

.collapsed {
  max-height: 20rem;
  overflow: hidden;
}
<div class="filler-content">filler content... scroll down</div>

<section>
  <p>this is the grid with grid items</p>
  <div id="grid">
    <div class="grid-item"></div>
    <div class="grid-item"></div>
    <div class="grid-item"></div>
    <div class="grid-item"></div>
    <div class="grid-item"></div>
    <div class="grid-item"></div>
    <div class="grid-item"></div>
    <div class="grid-item"></div>
    <div class="grid-item"></div>
    <div class="grid-item"></div>
    <div class="grid-item"></div>
    <div class="grid-item"></div>
    <div class="grid-item"></div>
    <div class="grid-item"></div>
    <div class="grid-item"></div>
    <div class="grid-item"></div>
    <div class="grid-item"></div>
    <div class="grid-item"></div>
  </div>

  <div id="toggle-button">Toggle</div>
</section>

<div class="filler-content">filler content.. press the toggle button when this text is above the button</div>




A little confused. You don't have code to jump to a section of a page. In my use, not programmatically, in a browser, when I click an element in view and there is a class/animation added the page, if the animation is in view, does scroll to follow the new content. You could tie the button click to an anchor on the top of the page, maybe an H1 but I kind of think this is expected behavior. You could add CSS or JS to visually animate the "show" instead of simply making it visible or not

That isn't happening for me in Chrome/Win11 (or I misunderstand the problem). Maybe try a Shift-refresh (to clear page cache) and try again.

When I test this nothing is "jumping".  The content is being hidden as expected.  If I'm scrolled past that content on the page then the rest of the page moves upward when the content is hidden (and downward when it is shown), which is expected.  Is that the behavior you're trying to describe?

Yes @David. I recorded a video to show this. At 6 seconds in this video https://streamable.com/t2cyu3 after you click the toggle button the page scrolls down all the way to the bottom of the page  way past the grid

The page is not "jumping".  What's happening is that content is being hidden, and everything after that content moves up to fill the space.
There may be other ways to address this, but one way that's worked for me is to (1) calculate if the viewport is currently past a given point (in this case the top of the "grid" element) and (2) if so, calculate the difference in height and scroll that amount.
For example:


const toggleButton = document.getElementById("toggle-button")

const grid = document.getElementById("grid")

let isExpanded = true

toggleButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  isExpanded = !isExpanded
  
  // get current element height and top position
  const oldHeight = grid.offsetHeight;
  const { top } = grid.getBoundingClientRect();

  if (isExpanded) {
    grid.classList.add("expanded")
  } else {
    grid.classList.remove("expanded")
  }
  
  // get new element height
  const newHeight = grid.offsetHeight;
  
  // if the top of the element is above the viewport, scroll the window by the height difference
  if (top < 0)
    window.scrollBy(0, newHeight - oldHeight);
})
body {
  padding: 72px;
}

.filler-content {
  background: seashell;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1600px;
}

#grid {
  background: black;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  gap: 16px;
}

.grid-item {
  background: blue;
  padding: 80px;
}

#toggle-button {
  background: orange;
  padding: 16px;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 4px;
}

.expanded {
  max-height: 20rem;
  overflow: hidden;
}
<div class="filler-content">filler content... scroll down</div>

<section>
  <p>this is the grid with grid items</p>
  <div id="grid" class="expanded">
    <div class="grid-item"></div>
    <div class="grid-item"></div>
    <div class="grid-item"></div>
    <div class="grid-item"></div>
    <div class="grid-item"></div>
    <div class="grid-item"></div>
    <div class="grid-item"></div>
    <div class="grid-item"></div>
    <div class="grid-item"></div>
    <div class="grid-item"></div>
    <div class="grid-item"></div>
    <div class="grid-item"></div>
    <div class="grid-item"></div>
    <div class="grid-item"></div>
    <div class="grid-item"></div>
    <div class="grid-item"></div>
    <div class="grid-item"></div>
    <div class="grid-item"></div>
  </div>

  <div id="toggle-button">Toggle</div>
</section>

<div class="filler-content">filler content.. press the toggle button when this text is above the button</div>



There of course may be edge cases, such as being scrolled to the bottom of the page at the time of toggling or perhaps different calculations to be made when expanding vs. collapsing the content.  You're encouraged to perform additional testing and debugging to find and address any such cases.
The main point here is that the page is not "jumping", you're simply hiding content that's earlier in the page.

About as good as possible of an answer for a question that doesn't make sense based on terminology of the issue.
